# Showing a menu badge

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hello any help please I need to configure holidays that can see bubble notification  in  menu Request to approve in hr officer and in admin not only on   manager departement.  it inherit from mail_thread I  try this : http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/odoo-count-badge-menu-notification.html and I try with this but I d'ont understand how can I do it  :

```
 def _track_subtype(self, init_values):
    if 'state' in init_values and self.state == 'validate':
        return 'hr_holidays.mt_holidays_approved'
    elif 'state' in init_values and self.state == 'validate1':
        return 'hr_holidays.mt_holidays_first_validated'
    elif 'state' in init_values and self.state == 'confirm':
        return 'hr_holidays.mt_holidays_confirmed'
    elif 'state' in init_values and self.state == 'refuse':
        return 'hr_holidays.mt_holidays_refused'
    return super(Holidays, self)._track_subtype(init_values).
```

I d'ont know how can I do it . actually only manager  can see the  badge menu in Request To Approve

[image: Showing a menu badge]